# how to display changes in list after deleting item from array flutter firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list view builder that takes in a list String called allcomments and builds a list with it. getSpecificComments Widget takes in the comments and checks whether it is the comments I want and then displays the comments as text on the page.
When I click onTap I want to delete one of the comments that come on the page.
I am correctly able to delete it from the comment array.

```
ListView.builder(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          itemCount: allcomments.length,

          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return ListTile(

              title: Column(

                children: [getSpecificComments(allcomments[index])],
              ),
                onTap: () async {

                  showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                      title: Text("Delete Event?"),

                      actions: [
                        TextButton(
                          child: Text("Cancel"),
                          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                        ),
                        TextButton(
                          child: Text("Ok"),
                          onPressed: () async {
                            await FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction myTransaction) async {
                              await  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('commentSections').doc('1T6k4dMAmECZXDzOsO44').update({'comments': FieldValue.arrayRemove([allcomments[index]])}).whenComplete((){
                                Navigator.pop(context);
                              });
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            });
                            

                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );




                }
              
            );

          }

      ),
```

The problem I am facing is that I can only see the array item deleted after I refresh the page. I want it so the moment I delete it, I can see the automatic update of the array without having to refresh. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: How do you get the value of `allcomments`?

Comment: The length of `itemCount: allcomments.length,` probably is not updated when you delete a comment. Thus, the builder does not rebuild itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the `ListView.builder()` with `StreamBuilder()` and use it for listing on the comments.

By this way the list of `allcomments` would change if any change happened to the data fetched from the stream.